# Javascript this in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw some old code that had:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="somefunction(this)" />
```

I was jQuery'ing the script, how do I get the pure javascript (this) object in jQuery?

```
$("input[name=submit]").click(function() {
  somefunction(// ?? is it $(this) );
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `this`, it refers to the clicked object, this is true for any jQuery event handler:

```
$("input[name=submit]").submit(function() {
  somefunction(this);
});
```

Or, better would be to use `this` *inside* the function, then it's just:

```
$("input[name=submit]").submit(somefunction);
```

This won't cover when it's not submitted via the button though, better to do it at the `<form>` level or via [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if it's dynamic.  Note that by doing this, it'll change `this` to refer to the `<form>` instead of the `<input>`, depending on your function you may need adjustments for that.

Answer (score 3):

It's still `this`.

The difference between `this` and `$(this)` is that `this` is the DOM element object itself, while `$(this)` is the DOM element encapsulated in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

The `submit()` event needs to be attached to the form, not the button.